# How to make proper curve in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, shapes

I'm new to draw **paths** programmatically and my project requirement is as following. (*forget the **red rectangle one**, it's for censor purpose only*).

[image]

And my current code be like

```
import SwiftUI

struct CurveShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY),
                      control1: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.70, y: rect.midY),
                      control2: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.25, y: rect.maxY * 1.25))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}

struct CurveShape_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CurveShape()
            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)
            .frame(height: 200)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

and current result is

[image]

anyway to do properly?

Comment: You're not going to be able to generate a complex shape like the one you want with a single curve. You'll need separate curves for each "corner" in your shape. I suggest taking a look at this post, which has a shape similar to yours: https://betterprogramming.pub/drawing-with-swiftuis-path-1cb3e57b9ee5

Comment: @cutiko, you have a point. I'll try your idea of single-rounded corner view.

Comment: @DuncanC And then I'll try the link Duncan C suggested. That's a lot both.

Comment: I haven't done much with Path() in SwiftUI so I decided to try to duplicate your shape. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create a closed path with a series of inside and outside corners.

The secret to doing this easily is the function `Path. addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:)`. With that function, you just specify the center point of the corner you want to draw, then the center-point of the next corner, plus a radius, and it does all the gory math for you to generate your rounded corners.

You can create a shape like what you want with code like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CurveShape: Shape {
    let smallRadius: CGFloat = 20
    let largeRadius: CGFloat = 100
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        // Define all the points we're going to use
        let upperLeft = CGPoint.zero
        let upperRight: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY)
        
        // We will start drawing in the top-middle of the shape.
        let midTop = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)
        
        // The "midRight" and "midLeft" points are the points where the large radius curves are centered.
        let midRight =  CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY - largeRadius * 2)
        let midLeft = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY - largeRadius * 2)

        //The bottom left is the lowest point on the shape.
        let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)

        var path = Path()
        // Start haflway along the top so we don't "cut a corner".
        path.move(to: midTop)
        
        // Draw a small-radius curve around the top right corner, headed to the mid right
        path.addArc(tangent1End: upperRight, tangent2End: midRight, radius: smallRadius, transform: .identity)
        
        // Now draw a large radius curve around the mid right, headed to the mid-left
        path.addArc(tangent1End: midRight, tangent2End: midLeft, radius: largeRadius, transform: .identity)

        // Now draw an outside curve down to the bottom left corner
        path.addArc(tangent1End: midLeft, tangent2End: bottomLeft, radius: largeRadius, transform: .identity)
        
        // Now draw a final curve around the top left corner and back to the top midpoint.
        path.addArc(tangent1End: upperLeft, tangent2End: midTop, radius: smallRadius, transform: .identity)
        
        // Close the path (which draws the final line from the top left curved corner to the top midpoint.
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CurveShape()
            .fill(Color.gray)
            .padding(.all, 20)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

That creates a shape like this:

[image]

### Edit:

Tweaking it some more, we can get quite close to your sample image:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.black)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 300)
                ZStack {
                    CurveShape()
                        .fill(Color(red: 0.15, green: 0.15, blue: 0.15))
                        .padding(.all, 20)
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 20)
                            Text("Phone")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            Spacer()
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
                            Text("Email/User ID")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That yields a screen that looks like the below. (You'll have to do some extra work to ignore the safe area and push the image up under the status bar as in your mockup.)

[image]

Comment: See the additional edits to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Color.blue
            .cornerRadius(50)
            .padding(.leading, -100)
            .padding(.top, -100)
            .background(.yellow)
        Color.yellow
            .cornerRadius(50)
            .padding(.trailing, -100)
            .padding(.bottom, -100)
            .background(.blue)
    }
    .clipped()
    .ignoresSafeArea()
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

I found it's best if the negative padding is much larger than the corner radius, otherwise you see some edges bleeding.

If you want to have content in the foreground, then just use the colored blocks as background. Like this:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    Color.blue
        .cornerRadius(50)
        .padding(.leading, -100)
        .padding(.top, -100)
        .background(.yellow)

    HStack(spacing: 50) {
        Text("Phone")
        Text("Email/User ID")
    }
    .font(.title2)
    .padding(.top, 20)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    .background {
        Color.yellow
            .cornerRadius(50)
            .padding(.trailing, -100)
            .padding(.bottom, -100)
            .background(.blue)
    }
}
.clipped()
.ignoresSafeArea()
```

[image: WithContent]

Comment: That doesn't look much like the OPs shape. See my answer. I think I got the shape he was after.

Comment: @DuncanC I based it on the grey/black background in the original image. I assumed the black at the edge was part of the display and not the frame of the device. But if it is the frame of the device, then it is just a matter of omitting the padding of 20 in my answer.

Comment: @DuncanC Actually, on closer inspection I think you're right, thanks for pointing it out. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Given the red shape the OP shows in their question, I interpret their question to be asking how to draw the gray shape at the top of the screen, and further that the rounded corners at the top are part of the desired output. My code attempts to duplicate that gray shape, including the rounded corners at the top.

Comment: If they also want the black shape at the bottom, it would be pretty easy to create a ZStack and add that black shape to it (if it's under the gray shape it would be trivial, since the gray shape would clip the top of the black shape.)